# Is Address randomization dependent to OS or compiler

Tags: linux, security, gcc, assembly, buffer-overflow

With ASLR enabled after compiling a program with gcc every time the program starts, its stack pointer changes. But this does not happen to a similar program coded in assembly and compiled with 'as' command. Stack pointer is always the same. Is OS not supposed to be responsible for ASLR?

My OS: Linux 64bit

Comment: It is the OS (which you didn't specify). Also you didn't say how you compiled. My test shows stack is randomized even for a simple assembler program, using debian linux and binutils 2.22.

Comment: I'm on linux x64 and compiled c program (which its rsp changes each time) with:
gcc sample.c -o sample
and the assembly one:
as a.asm -o a.obj && ld a.obj a
I think this is the compiler that causes some sort of protection. for example if using -z execstack, then DEP will be disabled.